# Can't Run Visual Studio 2019 after Windows update

Tags: visual-studio

Yesterday Windows made some automatic updates and since then I can't start Visual Studio 2019 Community. VS was launched and forcibly closed. Now, when I try to run it the splash screen displays and it suddenly disappears. After that there is no VS process in the background. The same thing happens with VS Installer, it runs for a second and closes. The installer bootstrapper performs the unpacking process and then closes. So I can't repair or uninstall it. I tried to run VS in safe mode but without success. I deleted installer folder but the installer bootstrapper won't start. I even reinstalled the .Net framework. I thought the problem could be in the "KB4580980 Cumulative Update Preview for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10", so I tried to uninstall it but error displayed and after restarting Windows some process was in progress maybe for an hour, but after logging in to Windows the update was still installed and moreover the message in update history says "Requires a restart to finish installing".

The errors I can see are in the [ActivityLog.xml](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Avn0ro7ju16ygg6RZFh0Ct9pdaUO?e=Cl0iNa) file of Visual Studio.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post this in the VS developer forums.

Answer (score 1):

The last update solved the issue. I made an update to "Feature update to Windows 10, version 20H2" and Visual Studio launched fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like your making things worse. I would make sure all your windows updates are installed and then re-install VS.

If that doesnt work:

> Start->Settings->Recovery->Go Back to the previous version of Windows
> 10

Then re-install VS.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I didn't have that option available. Windows didn't even make a restore point before update.

Comment: @Sasha Are you sure?...anyway I added an image.